# MySQL “subquery returns more than 1 row” error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1242

I am trying to calculate the sum of the products which a client can order based on the product id and the quantity needed.

```
[CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `calculate_sum`()
BEGIN
  SELECT  
        (SELECT produs_comandat.idComanda 
        FROM produs_comandat 
        WHERE produs_comandat.idComanda <= comanda.idComanda) AS idComanda,
         (SELECT client.idClient 
         FROM client 
         WHERE client.idClient <= comanda.idClient)AS idClient,
         (SELECT SUM( produs.pret )
          FROM produs_comandat
           INNER JOIN produs ON produs.idProdus = produs_comandat.idProdus
           WHERE comanda.idComanda <= produs_comandat.idComanda) AS suma
    FROM  comanda
    ORDER BY 
    (SELECT produs_comandat.cantitate 
    FROM produs_comandat
    WHERE produs_comandat.idComanda <= comanda.idComanda);

END][1]
```

Comment: It might be due to subqueries in select clause, but before that, try removing `order by` clause and check again. Order by needs a column, not values.

Comment: A subquery in the select list must return a single value, it cannot return multiple records. The subquery in the order by clause also seems to be incorrect. You should provide us with sample data an expected outcome based on the data in your question. We will probably be able to suggest a solution based on those. Do not remove your attempt from the question, it is a demonstration that you have tried.